# RIGHT/LEFT OUTER JOIN perform differently in HIVE?

Tags: join, hive

Does "RIGHT OUTER JOIN" and "LEFT OUTER JOIN" perform differently in HIVE?

For example, Table A is a small table. Table B is much larger and partitioned on col2.

Query 1:
`SELECT * 
FROM A RIGHT OUTER JOIN B on (A.col=B.col)
WHERE B.col2>20131001`

Query 2:
`SELECT * 
FROM A LEFT OUTER JOIN B on (A.col=B.col)
WHERE B.col2>20131001`

Query 1 only scans a small number of partitions, but Query 2 scans all partitions of Table B. Is it a bug or I miss something?

Thanks!

Comment: You mean partitioning is by the `col2` (time) and the `B.col2>20131001` filter does not prune partitions on second case? Can you post the EXPLAIN plans for the two?

Comment: You should also read [MapJoin & Partition Pruning](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=34015666) and see if your case fits the problem description.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same (don't know why this, bug or feature. i would consider this definately as a bug). Since left outer join is heavily used by me, i use the following workaround:

```
SELECT *
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  (SELECT *
   FROM B
   WHERE B.COL2 >20131001) ON (A.COL=B.COL)
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B ON (A.COL= B.COL
                      AND B.COL2 > 20131001)
```

I'm working on Hive 0.11 ... would be interesting if this is fixed in later versions.

Answer (score 0):

Query 1 table B is preserved table so B's where predicate is pushdown.

Query 2 table B is not preserved table so B's where predicate will not pushdown.hive will
scan the entire table B

see this for more detail [OuterJoinBehavior](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/OuterJoinBehavior)